# synchronize user configurations between multiple machines on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sync

I have multiple Ubuntu boxes and I need to synchronize config files between them.
The config files are both system global ones in /etc and user ones like ~/.emacs

What do you think is the best way to do it? So far I am doing it using Dropbox: the config files to be synced are placed in Dropbox folder and then I simply create symlinks to these files on every system.

The systems are not identically the same, I only need some files to be synced, not all of them.

This seems to be a quick and dirty solution. Perhaps there is a better solution you could recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Have a [look](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) at [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) file synchronization tool, it is designed for things like that.